# How do i group all expenses of the same category in django?

Tags: django

I am new to Django and trying to group and retrieve all expenses of the same category together and retrieve them in one "link like" table raw which when clicked can then display all the expenses in that category in another form.

**I have these Models:**

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
        unique_together = ("name",)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Expense(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateField(default=now, )
    description = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date', '-pk']
```

**homeView:**

```py
def home(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    expenses = Expense.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    paginator = Paginator(expenses, 5)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = Paginator.get_page(paginator, page_number)
    currency = UserPreference.objects.filter(user=request.user)  # .currency
    query = Expense.objects.values('category').annotate(total=Sum(
                                    'amount')).order_by('category')
    context = {
        'expenses': expenses,
        'page_obj': page_obj,
        'currency': currency,
        'query': query
    }

    return render(request, 'expenses/home.html', context)
```

**mytemplate:**

```
<div class="app-table"> 
  <table class="table table-stripped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
    {% for myquery in query %}
      <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="https://www.mavtechplanet.com/">
        <td>{{myquery.category }}</td>
      </tr>
    
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    
  </table>
</div>
```

I am trying to figure out things but are not coming out clearly. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your template :

```
{% for myquery in query %}
     <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="https://www.mavtechplanet.com/">
        <td><a href = "{% url 'yourapp:showCategoryExpenses' myquery.category %}">{{myquery.category}}</a></td>
     </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

add url to urls.py where in yourapp like this,

```py
from youraapp.views import showCategoryExpenses

urlpatterns=[
.
.
.
path("/categoryExpenses/<pk:categoryPk>", showCategoryExpenses, name = "showCategoryExpenses"),
# if you save categories to expense with their name, you must change the <pk:categoryPk> to <slug:categoryName>
]
```

and add this view to yourapp.views like this:

```py
def showCategoryExpenses(request, categoryPk): # if you save categories to expense with their name, change categoryPk to categoryName
    expenses = Expense.objects.filter(category = categoryPk) # or category = categoryName
    context = {
        "expenses" : expenses
    }
    return render(request, "expenses/categoryExpenses.html", context)
```

and last, add this template to your template folder.. My English skills are not good but i try the solve and explain it. Maybe this is the answer you're looking for.

If you want show sum of all expenses in the category in this template, you can do it:

```
def showCategoryExpenses(request, categoryPk): # if you save categories to expense with their name, change categoryPk to categoryName
    expenses = Expense.objects.filter(category = categoryPk) # or category = categoryName
    expensesSum = 0
    for expense in expenses:
        expensesSum += expense.amount
    context = {
        "expenses" : expenses,
        "expensesSum" : expensesSum
    }
    return render(request, "expenses/categoryExpenses.html", context)
```

Comment: it works well and i am grateful for your  help but still if i needed to see the sum of all the items in that category like this....  **Category**      **CategorySum** whereby the category will be displayed with the sum of all expenses in that same raw. how can i achieve that? Sorry for disturbance but still need your help.

Comment: it was a mater of reasoning within the first answer you posted for me, the edits were not really necessary but was an eye opener and helped me to think and figure out everything required. your answer perfectly worked for me, here i mark it correct and i am very grateful brother. Thanks a lot and be blessed.

Comment: Thank you so so much brother, you are welcome, thank you so much for your good words. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Once you have `categoryPk`, you can try this way

```
from django.db.models import Sum

expenses = Expense.objects.filter(category = categoryPk).annotate(category_sum = Sum('amount')).values('category','category_sum')

# {'category':'ABC','category_sum':3000}
```

If you don't have any pk and want to annotate all objects then

```
expenses = Expense.objects.values('category').annotate(category_sum = Sum('amount')).values('category','category_sum')
```